# Why robot_model use urdf not just using universal CAD extension file?

Tags: ros, urdf, cad, solidworks

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Because translate from CAD file to urdf will lead to a lot of steps or problems.

I have occurred some.

I am afraid of that maybe also cause some precisions problems during translation.

Is there any way just read the file from Inventor,Solidworks,Proe...?

Or is it possible in the future?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10664/why-robot_model-use-urdf-not-just-using-universal-cad-extension-file?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2011-07-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

URDF contains more information that CAD files, i.e. it is more universal.
You can, however, use models imported from CAD programs in the URDF.

Extra things that are handled are e.g. kinematics, joint limits (those might be in CAD programs), extensions for simulation, collision models.

Also a URDF is very small to read if you don't care about the CAD models.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-07-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2011-07-20**:
I think theoretically CAD software could export URDF, but it is not widely used enough to be on their radar. Plus its not just one piece of CAD software.

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-07-20**:
So information like materials, screw threads, and etc are not important with gazebo,right?

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-07-20**:
And........if URDF is more universal,why CAD software couldn't export to that extension? Is URDF a different type of purpose,so CAD software just ignore that?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-07-20**:
I'd say it depends on the format. Regarding your question the word "Unified" is the most important from the URDF. You can attach meshes (i.e. CAD models) to the URDF, but information like materials, screw threads, etc. will be lost.

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-07-20**:
What you mean is URDF contain all the information of CAD files,and also contain with other features that CAD files don't concern?  And is there any possible lose from transfer CAD files to URDF?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [simmechanics to urdf](http://www.ros.org/wiki/simmechanics_to_urdf) tool is one way to get data from CAD programs to ROS.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2011-07-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2